# Instagram API get followers list

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am using Instagram public API using the following endpoint but am only getting details of one follower in the response. Why is the API returning only one follower (that is part of sandbox users, none else)?

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN where ACCESS_TOKEN is one I got from Instagram.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is in sandbox mode, you can't access data of users other than listed in sandbox users.

As mentioned in **API Behavior** section of this [documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/)

Data is restricted to sandbox users and the 20 most recent media from each sandbox user.

Comment: For notice, the instagram api to get followers will be deprecated at 31st July 2018 [Source](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/01/30/instagram-graph-api-updates/)

Comment: i can not get even my followers?